# What to call variables that measures human's random preferences to select a given experimental stimuli?

Tags: terminology, statistics

I understand that in some cases, given a set of objects, human subjects asked to randomly select one will tend to favor one over others.

We all know the situation where "37" will be favored when asked to select a random number between 1 and 100, and I'd once heard that the top right square of a square divided into four squares will be favored, etc.

My question is: what is the **name** for these types of variables? (Schleiderman Variables? Steinman Variables?...)

Thank you.

Comment: I think it's called a [Schelling point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Focal_point_(game_theory)).

Comment: @Arnon I think you're correct [link](https://messari.io/resource/schelling-point).  I'd not been aware of the cooperative aspect of the term, only that, given some range of choices, some were more likely to be chosen than others.